# Image Database - One Table or Two?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I'm putting together a database to manage image files located on a file server. As I'm new to the database world, I'm torn between using one table, or two. Here's the breakdown:

I'm needing columns for: `imgId, imgTitle, imgClass, imgFamily`, and `imgURL`.

I'm wondering if it would be better to put the `imgURL` in another table with `imgID` linking the two, or if they can all be together in one table, and function fine.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the items that you have stated appear to have a one to one relationship; in other words, you're probably not going to have two different URLs for one title or image id.

However, the other thing to consider is whether any of the fields are likely to be empty fairly often; would a lot of them have no class, for example, or family?  If that was the case, you could consider putting that data in a separate table and linking to it using the id:

```
CREATE TABLE `image` (
  `imgId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imgTitle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imgURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imgDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imgId`),
  KEY `date` (`imgDate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `imageAddendum` (
  `imgId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `imgClass` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imgFamily` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imgId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

You would then get your data using a LEFT JOIN, which would therefore get you the data in image even if there were no row in imageAddendum:

```
SELECT i.imgId, i.imgTitle, i.imgURL, i.imgDate, ia.imgClass, ia.imgFamily
 FROM image i LEFT JOIN imageAddendum ia using ( imgId );
```

Comment: It wouldn't change the answer, no.  But I did edit the answer ;)  I added the date column to the main 'image' table as I figure it would be something you'd have for every image, and added a key to it so that the query to order it would be faster.  The only thing to think about is whether you want just a date, or a date and time; the example I gave is a date and time, but clearly you might only want a date.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Im using phpMyAdmin to create my columns. What does KEY relate to? I understand primary key, but not just KEY. Oh, and is it necessary to define the length/value of each type?

Comment: Key is another word for Index.  With a primary key, you can only have one row with the same value(s).  With a key, you can have lots of rows with the same value(s).  For your table, you probably want a PRIMARY key on imgId to make sure they are unique, but you may want to keep imgDate a key because you might have lots of images from the same date (or datetime).  I'm not sure I understood the last question.

Comment: I also have been told that for the imgId I should use Auto_Increment. Am I right to assume that if I do so, the database will define the id automatically as I enter the data? In your code you made the default 0.

Comment: Your assumption is correct if you set the value to NULL; for example "INSERT INTO image SET imgURL = 'foo';" will therefore set the imgId to the next available integer if, as you say, you make it auto_increment.  The default of 0 should therefore be changed to not null.  I'll go change my answer again ;) (and i've changed the int to unsigned, because I hate signed ints unless you really want negative numbers)

Comment: As you can see, I really need a teacher. I'm sorry for being such a bother, and I do appreciate all your help. I've put together my database using the perimeters you provided, and so far so good. I'm wondering, what is the best way to insert data? I can do it through phpMyAdmin which has an auto date/time input, but creating an html/php form has the bonus of selection fields as the family and class of my images are from a finite list of choices.

Comment: @KennyScott let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2446/discussion-between-stefmikhail-and-kenny-scott)

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing just the Image URL - a string of fairly finite length (a few hundred characters - at most) - I don't see any big benefit in breaking that column into a separate table.

If you would be storing the image per se (the bytes making up the image) - then yes, in many systems, it would make sense to store this blob (binary large object) into a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason you might want to split the tables would be if there is the possibility that there might not be a one-to-one match in some cases between imgId and imgURL - like two or more Ids for the same URL; or the same ID referring to more than one URL. (An empty URL would be fine, however. Otherwise, you're fine with one table.